# The doted nine patch lines shows up in the ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton, nine-patch

My nine patch ImageButtons are showing nine patch -Lines
[image: The doted nine patch lines shows up in the ImageButton]

(There is dotted line on the left of first ImageButton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you resized the image after you made it 9-patch?

Comment: Ya. Thnaks!! that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is known, just clean your project and run again

*Eclipse>project>clean*

If still problem exist then Uninstall your application and then install

Comment: Even Made one ImageButton to Button and set the backgroung of it as my 9-patch image.. but then also it shows up

Comment: Anything to consider for dotted 9patch?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you removed .9 from its name . mostly people do this mistakenly  during rename . like `nine_patch.9.png` is rename as `new_name.png` istead of `new_name.9.png`

Comment: All the images are having proper extensions. The buttons with dotted patch are only showing up with Lines.